# How to make a method to wait for a POST method to end?

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I do have this code:

```
login() {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      "usuario":"juanma",
      "password":"1234"});
    console.log(body);
    let tokencito:string = ''
    const params = new HttpParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.post<AuthResponse>("http://localhost:8000/login", body, {'headers':headers,'params':params})
      .subscribe(data =>
        // @ts-ignore
     this.tokencito = data.token.token, localStorage.setItem('token', this.tokencito));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  }
```

I'm using this to get a token from a user on PHP. However, It does not wait for the data to arrive. When I do it one time, it gives me that 'data' it's undefined. But when I do a second time, it does get the token right.

I'll add an image to explain it better:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it wait for the post method to end?

Comment: this.tokencito = data.token.token, localStorage.setItem('token', this.tokencito));
Is the comma a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, this is what you want:

```js
  login() {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      usuario: 'juanma',
      password: '1234',
    });
    console.log(body);
    const params = new HttpParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/login', body, { headers: headers, params: params }).subscribe((data) => {
      this.tokencito = data.token.token;
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.tokencito);
    });
  }
```

Try not to override TypeScript. It's trying to tell you something.